# Can anyone suggest a good papers or articles on the architecture of graphics drivers?

Tags: opengl, graphics, directx, 3d

I'm wondering about how exactly OpenGL and DirectX drivers work. From what I know, they basically take in calls in their various APIs, and output a stream of bytecode instructions that head off to the GPU to be executed.

I know GPU chipmakers are extremely secretive about the details of their specifications. Are there any documents that describe how the APIs themselves are implemented on a level above the card itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AMD has released some [specification documents](http://developer.amd.com/documentation/guides/Pages/default.aspx#open_gpu) that you may find interesting.

The [Gallium3D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallium3D) folks are building on top of that to produce open drivers for recent Radeon cards.  You can check out the [source](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/tree/src/gallium?h=gallium-0.2).

Comment: But what *exactly* is it that graphics drivers do? Aside from making video happen.

Comment: @Green: You have the [`nouveau`](http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/) folks, though they're working solely with reverse-engineered information.  For whatever reason NVidia hasn't been forthcoming with spec documents for their chipsets.

Comment: @Alex: They turn graphic API calls into commands to/for the graphics card and do all the bookkeeping required, like managing the framebuffers, maintaining on-screen buffer, care for the pixel ownership data, etc. If you really want to know what a graphics driver does, you will have to read the source code of one.